# Restrict a MySQL foreign key based on another column value ("foreign key to a view's column")?

Tags: mysql, access-rights

My main goal is to have a database user that I can restrict access rights so they won't see some confidential stuff, while still being able to use foreign keys for integrity checks. So the `foo` user below must be allowed to only see the `PUBLIC` items, while still being able to make a foreign key on their `other_data` table so that table won't contain any `id_item` value theyr wouldn't be able to see.

Here is the setup:

```sql
-- These are items with a visibility
CREATE TABLE items (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    item_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    visibility ENUM('PUBLIC','PRIVATE','DELETED') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'PRIVATE',
    INDEX (visibility),
    UNIQUE INDEX (item_name)
)
ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO items (id, item_name, visibility) 
    VALUES (1, 'x', 'PUBLIC'), (2, 'y', 'PRIVATE'), (3, 'z', 'DELETED'), (4, 'xprime', 'PUBLIC'), (5, 'yprime', 'PRIVATE'), (6, 'zprime', 'DELETED');

-- This view only shows the public items (not private ones, not deleted ones)
CREATE VIEW public_items AS 
    (SELECT id, item_name FROM items WHERE visibility = 'PUBLIC');

-- How can I make this table definition only allow id_item to be a value from public_items.id?
-- I cannot use the view in the constraint, tho it would be perfect solution
CREATE TABLE other_data (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    label VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    id_item INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY (label),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (id_item) REFERENCES /*public_*/items (id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
)ENGINE=INNODB;


-- Let's create the foo user that I want to restrict access rights
CREATE USER 'foo'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'bar';
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'foo'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT ON test_sql.public_items TO 'foo'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT,INSERT ON test_sql.other_data TO 'foo'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

```sql
-- Now, use foo@localhost user

-- This should return (1;4) because foo must be allowed to see the public items => OK
SELECT * FROM public_items;

-- This should be DENIED because foo is not allowed to see all other items => OK
SELECT * FROM items;

-- This should be ALLOWED because foo is allowed to insert rows in other_data => OK
-- and this row refers to a public item
INSERT INTO other_data (id, label, id_item) VALUES (11, 'allowed-public', 1);

-- This should be ALLOWED because foo is allowed to see all the other_data => OK
SELECT * FROM other_data;

-- This should be FORBIDDEN because the item is not public => FAIL, it can be inserted...
INSERT INTO other_data (id, label, id_item) VALUES (12, 'forbidden-private', 2);

-- This should be FORBIDDEN because the item is not public => FAIL, it can be inserted
INSERT INTO other_data (id, label, id_item) VALUES (13, 'forbidden-deleted', 3);

-- This should be FORBIDDEN because the item does not exist => OK, it cannot be inserted
INSERT INTO other_data (id, label, id_item) VALUES (19, 'forbidden-notexist', 9);
```

I'm using mysql 5.7 here, so I could have use a generated column in the `items` table that would be like `id_if_public INT UNSIGNED GENERATED ALWAYS AS IF(visibility = 'PUBLIC', id, NULL) STORED` and put my FK on this column but generated columns forbid referencing an auto-increment (`id`) column...

I could move to MySQL 8 for the `CHECK` syntax to be used on `other_data` like `CHECK EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM public_items WHERE public_items.id = other_data.id_item)` but is seems `CHECK` does not allow subqueries...

I could turn the `public_items` into a table and "maintain" it using `TRIGGER` and such, but it feels very heavy and complex, and requires extra storage for the `item_name` so it's not perfectly extensible (ie: the more columns in `items`, the heavier!)

Answer (score 0):

Having such a new table `public_items` isn't a bad idea since you need something to have a foreign key on. You can combine it with a view to get the meta information from the `items` table so you don't need to add them in the new `public_items` table twice. The tables should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    item_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    visibility ENUM('PUBLIC','PRIVATE','DELETED') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'PRIVATE',
    INDEX (visibility),
    UNIQUE INDEX (item_name),
    UNIQUE INDEX (id, visibility) /* new index over 'id' and 'visibility' */
);
```

Now you create a new table `public_items` with the foreign key over `(id, visibility)`, but enforce that only `"PUBLIC"` entries can be used.

```
CREATE TABLE public_items (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    visibility ENUM('PUBLIC') NOT NULL, /* only allow public items */

    CONSTRAINT FK_public_items_id_visibility FOREIGN KEY (id, visibility) 
                                             REFERENCES items(id, visibility)
);
```

Now you can only add rows from `items` in `public_items` which are public and you can reference *these* rows by a foreign key. Your `other_data` table has to change the foreign key to this new `public_items` table.

Obviously that approach has some drawbacks:

- You have to maintain the list of public items in `public_items` with entries from the "source" table `items`. You can use TRIGGERs or a background process to keep these entries in sync or any other approach.
- The `public_items` table does not have the `item_name` column. You might still need a view to get the public items with their meta information from the `items` table if you don't want to copy these meta information to the `public_items` table (with the sync/update process mentioned above).